# Custom Wordpress Select Input Field Not Working on Iphone(JQuery Problem)

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress

I created some custom select input fields in WordPress and they work perfectly except for 1 which I wrote JQuery for. It works on my laptop and Android but doesn't work on iPhone. What can I do to make it work?
I edited my question and removed unnecessary codes. Thank you.

Note: When I comment out the JQuery at the bottom, the select field works but it doesn't show the images, when I uncomment it the problem continues, there's no response when the field is clicked

```
        <div class="wdm-custom-fields">
            <label for="fabric">Fabric:</label>
            <br />
            <select id="id_select2_example" name="Fabric" style="width: 150px;" required>
                <option disabled selected value>Choose a Fabric</option>
                <option data-img_src="https://neyah.ng/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/Multi-coloured-Flowery-Fabric.jpg" value="Multi-coloured Flowery Fabric">Multi-coloured Flowery Fabric</option>
                <option data-img_src="https://neyah.ng/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/Leopard-Print-Fabric.jpg" value="Leopard Print Fabric">Leopard Print Fabric</option>
                <option data-img_src="https://neyah.ng/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/Green-Plain-Fabric.jpg" value="Green Plain Fabric">Green Plain Fabric</option>
                <option data-img_src="https://neyah.ng/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/Gold-and-Black-Print-Fabric--rotated.jpg" value="Gold and Black Print Fabric">Gold and Black Print Fabric</option>
                <option data-img_src="https://neyah.ng/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/Black-Plain-Fabric.jpg" value="Black Plain Fabric">Black Plain Fabric</option>
                <option data-img_src="https://neyah.ng/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/Black-and-Gold-Print-Fabric.jpg" value="Black and Gold Print Fabric">Black and Gold Print Fabric</option>
                <option data-img_src="https://neyah.ng/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/Torquoise-Print-Fabric.jpg" value="Torquoise Print Fabric">Torquoise Print Fabric</option>
                <option data-img_src="https://neyah.ng/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/Teal-Print-Fabric.jpg" value="Teal Print Fabric">Teal Print Fabric</option>
                <option data-img_src="https://neyah.ng/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/Snakeskin-Print-Fabric-rotated.jpg" value="Snakeskin Print Fabric">Snakeskin Print Fabric</option>
                <option data-img_src="https://neyah.ng/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/Red-and-Black-Print-Fabric.jpg" value="Red and Black Print Fabric">Red and Black Print Fabric</option>
                <option data-img_src="https://neyah.ng/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/Nude-Plain-Fabric.jpg" value="Nude Plain Fabric">Nude Plain Fabric</option>
                <option data-img_src="https://neyah.ng/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/Nude-and-Blue-Print-Fabric.jpg" value="Nude and Blue Print Fabric">Nude and Blue Print Fabric</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    <!-- scripts -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function custom_template(obj){
            var data = $(obj.element).data();
            var text = $(obj.element).text();
            if(data && data['img_src']){
                img_src = data['img_src'];
                template = $("<div><img src=\"" + img_src + "\" style=\"width:35%;height:200px;padding:20px 0 5px 0;margin:10px 0 0 0;\"/><p style=\"font-weight: 700;font-size:14pt;text-align:left;\">" + text + "</p></div>");
                return template;
            }
        }
    var options = {
        'templateSelection': custom_template,
        'templateResult': custom_template,
    }
    $('#id_select2_example').select2(options);
    $('.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single').css({'height': '225px'});
    
    
    
    
    //----------------------------------------------------------

</script>
```

Comment: "doesn't work" - what does that mean? Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem?

Comment: A Js problem. "Doesn't work" means it doesn't drop down when clicked.

Comment: `onChange="custom_template(obj)"` - what is `obj` supposed to be? Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If this ia a JS problem, please remove the other tags, and the irrelevant code

Comment: Please ignore the onChange attribute, I was trying out some solutions I saw on StackOverflow. In fact I'll remove it now.

Comment: @NicoHaase I have edited and removed unnecessary code.